# How to parallelize a UNIX for-loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop, unix, parallel-processing, slurm

I apologize for the somewhat simple question (I am new to UNIX programming). I am using an HPC system and would like to parallelize a task in a for loop (in this case, a simple unzip to be applied to several files).
How could I do this? I thought that by requesting multiple cores the parallelization would start automatically, but actually the program is operating sequentially.
Thank you very much!

```
for i in *.zip; do unzip "$i" -d "${i%%.zip}"; done
```

Comment: Please show the code.

Answer (score 1):

In bash it would look something like:

```bash
for item in bunch-of-items; do
  (
    the loop body
    is here
  ) &
done
```

Where the parentheses group the commands, and the whole loop body is put in the background.

If the rest of your program needs all the background jobs to complete, use the `wait` command.

Comment: thank you glenn, it works! I was wondering if it would be convenient to use a third-party software (e.g., parallel) to indicate the number of parallel jobs to be performed (e.g., if I wanted to perform 10 jobs at a time). thanks!

Comment: Clearly it would be much more convenient than trying to code that yourself.